# Scanning different data types in C

Tags: c

I want to write a program, at first I input a number N, then I want to get the name (can consist of multiple words) and price of N items one by one. Example:

```
3
item a // the name can consist of multiple words
25.00
item b
12.50
item c
8.12
```

Next I want to process this data, however i got stuck on the scanning part. my code looks like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int n;
  char name[50];
  int price;

  scanf("%d\n", &n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%s\n%d",name,&price);
    printf("%s , %d", name, price);
  }
  printf("end");

}
```

This works for a single word item, but if the item has a space in it will not continue scanning. I tried using the `gets()` function, however I still don't have the right result. the code:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    gets(name);
    scanf("%d\n",&price);
    printf("%s , %d\n", name, price);
  }
  printf("end");
```

returns:

```
3             // Input 3 items
item a        // name of first item
1             // price of item 1
item b        // name of item 2
item a , 1    // the print of the first item
2             // price of item 2
item c        // name of item 3
item b , 2    // print of item 2
3             // price of item 3
word          // no clue where this new input came from
end           // end of scanning
```

My question is, how would I go about correctly scanning an input such as this? I also tried changing the scan function into  `while((c = getchar()) != '\n');`, but got the same result...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to read scanf with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718819/how-to-read-scanf-with-spaces)

Comment: not really, unless I dont understand how to use fgets(). putting fgets(name, 50, stdin) also  does not print out the string correctly.

Comment: Sorry I was looking at your last code block and had a thouhgt that that is your input. I am used to `dba` formatting.

Comment: Well, I took time to compile and run your program. It does not produce output you did mention.

Comment: It works on a single word name, however it does not work with multiple word names

Comment: If your definition of "works" is a random output, then yes, it works. How do you differentiate between outputs of a different invocations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing `gets()`, `scanf()` is bad as `scanf()` tends to leave the trailing `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Using `gets()` is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

`scanf("%s", ...)` is not useful for reading a line of info with spaces meant to be saved.

---

> how would I go about correctly scanning an input such as this?

A simple alternative is to read each *line* into a *string* and then parse the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char line[100];
  int n;

  fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
  sscanf(line, "%d", &n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    char name[50];
    // int price;
    double price;
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
    sscanf(line, " %49[^\n]", name);
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
    // sscanf(line, "%d", &price);
    sscanf(line, "%lf", &price);
    printf("%s , %.2f\n", name, price);
  }
  printf("end");

}
```

Advanced: Better code would check the return values of `fgets(), sscanf()`.  Maybe replace `sscanf(line, "%lf",...` with `strtod()`.

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you. Also learned not to use gets() in my code...

Comment: A red flag with this solution is that if the length of *name* is changed the rest won't follow since the format string is hard-coded. Also there is no validation of the input.

Comment: @August it can be sorted out as well. First of all `#define NAME_LEN 50` followed by something like `sprintf(format, " %%49[^\n]", NAME_LEN-1);` and finally `sscanf(line, format, name);`

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I find this [Specifying the maximum string length to scanf dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460242/2410359) solution interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably figure out what's happening here pretty easily if you added some more output. Let's try shall we?

Also, first of all you're really looking for a double input - not an integer. With an integer, your scan function won't match properly based on what you're looking for. But let's add some more output!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char name[50];
    double price;

    printf("Enter count: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", "Please type a name followed by a newline followed by a number and then press enter:");
        scanf("%s\n%lf", name, &price);
        printf("%s , %lf", name, price);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I think what was happening in your initial attempt was a combination of things. Mostly that you were possibly pressing enter after the output from the first iteration? That will break the scanf call - since it isn't expecting to start with a `\n` but it is immediately expecting you to enter a name.

Second, I don't know the number you entered in the first iteration, because you didn't supply the output of it while still using scanf - so I have nothing other than speculation. You possibly used an integer on the first go, and subsequently on the remaining iterations you chose to use decimals? Again, this is only a guess.

Comment: I tried your code and it runs well when the name consists of one word. However when i try naming an item "Item A", it starts to bug out, does not wait for the number input and instead immediately prints out the first item.

Comment: Oh I see. Then you should probably break apart the `scanf()` call. It is literally taking something before the specified space as the name! That's what the function does

Answer (score 1):

As `chux` said in the comments of this answer: "*All scan specifiers, except %c, %[, %n consumes leading white-spaces.*" So you don't need to account for them.

```
scanf("%s%d",name,&price);
```

And looking at your input, you should use `float` or `double` for the price.

```
scanf("%s%lf",name,&price);
```

Note that this works only if items are made of one word. If they can be of two or more words, you'd better use `fgets`

EDIT: for items made of more words you should use `fgets`

```
fgets(name, 50, stdin);
scanf("%lf",&price);
```

Comment: "%d automatically skip spaces, %s do not." ---> Both `"%d"` and `"%s"` skip leading white-space.

Comment: As far as I know I need `%d %s` to read `123 abc`, but I can do `%s%d` to read `abc 123`

Comment: Your code works with a single word name, however I am looking for an answer that also works if the name consists of more than one word.

Comment: @Davide `"%d%s"` also reads `"123 abc"` and `"%s %d"` reads `"abc 123"`.  All scan specifiers, expect `%c, %[, %n`, consumes leading white-spaces.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are right! I tried it and it works. It's nice to learn new stuff while trying to teach something. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your for loop with this:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf(" %[^\n]\n%d", name, &price);
        printf("%s , %d\n", name, price);
    }
```

The first space skips leading spaces, and the [^\n] allows you to get more than one word as string input.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is easier to just write your own functions with error checking. Below is a suggestion. You may also want to check that the numbers are non-negative.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ReadLine(char result[], int resultLen)
{
    int ch, i;

    assert(resultLen > 0);

    i = 0;
    ch = getchar();
    while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
        if (i < resultLen - 1) {
            result[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
}


void ReadInteger(int *i)
{
    int ch, count;

    count = scanf("%d", i);
    if (count == 1) {
        do {
            ch = getchar();
        } while (isspace(ch) && (ch != '\n'));
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input, integer expected\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}



void ReadReal(double *x)
{
    int ch, count;

    count = scanf("%lf", x);
    if (count == 1) {
        do {
            ch = getchar();
        } while (isspace(ch) && (ch != '\n'));
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input, real number expected\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    char name[50];
    int n;
    double price;

    ReadInteger(&n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ReadLine(name, sizeof name);
        ReadReal(&price);
        printf("%s, %.2f\n", name, price);
    }
    return 0;
}
```